# RFID надежнее NFC?

Tags: nfc

На производстве возникла задача, сделать систему пропусков, есть 2 варианта RFID и NFC, но к сожалению в интернете полным полно статей поделать и скопировать RFID метки, возник вопрос, NFC возможно взломать или скопировать? NFC труднее подается этому?

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте! Для начала скажем, что NFC - это та же RFID, только "ближнепольная". 
Я работаю с системами RFID несколько лет и могу Вам порекомендовать HF-технологию RFID с использованием меток Mifare и считывателей OMNIKEY Cardman. Это оптимальное решение для КПП. 
По поводу копирования пропусков - вопрос решаем. Метки могут быть "запаролены".